# Is there a 'tree of responsibility' design pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm quite new at design patterns, and I want to understand, if there is a 'tree of responsibility' design pattern, as a variation of 'chain of responsibility'?

Comment: SO is not the right place to discuss tech themes. It's about Q&A in a concret technical case. But IMHO a tree is just an implementation of chains.

Comment: The classic GoF design pattern representing a tree is called [Composite](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite). You could certainly use this structure to delegate responsibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In addition to a simple Handler implementation https://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

```
/// <summary>

  /// The 'Handler' abstract class

  /// </summary>

  abstract class Handler

  {
    protected Handler successor;

    public void SetSuccessor(Handler successor)
    {
      this.successor = successor;
    }

    public abstract void HandleRequest(int request);
  }
```

You'd do something like this  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20108/Extending-Chain-of-Responsibility-Design-Pattern:

```
public class IfHandler : Handler<string>
{
    private Case1Handler case1Handler;
    private Case2Handler case2Handler;

    public IfHandler(Case1Handler case1, Case2Handler case2)
    {
        case1Handler = case1;
        case2Handler = case2;
    }
    public override bool MustExecuteHandleActions(string request)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public override void PassRequestToNextHandlers(string request)
    {
        if (request != null)
            case1Handler.Handle(request);
        else
            case2Handler.Handle(request);
    }
}
```